# Smallest and largest value of concatenation (is8601dt ) in SAS

Tags: sas

I’m having trouble with my SAS coding today, any kind of your generous help or small advice would be grateful for me.

Here i have two char  Variables IMDT and IMST  .

IMDT          IMST

20110113     1306

20110119     1530

20110224       .

20110314       .

1) How to get the smallest value concatenation of both IMDT and IMST in is8601dt format ?

2) How to get the  largest value of concatination of both IMDT and IMST in is8601dt format ?

Krishna

Comment: Can you confirm if the values are stored as numeric or character?  The periods in the last 2 rows suggest numeric, but you mention char.

Comment: Both are char.The dataset contains around 200 observations.The IMDT varibles has data in all observations but not for IMST.My need is to find the smallest value among the concatenation of both IMDT and IMST and should be in iso8601 format.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing this is you dataset:

```
data times;
input IMDT $ IMST $;
datalines;
20110113 1306
20110119 1530
20110224 .
20110314 .
;
run;
```

You can convert the character values to numeric values in the format you want using this code:

```
data conversion;
set times;
if missing(imst) then date_time = dhms(input(imdt,yymmdd8.),0,0,0);
else date_time = dhms(input(imdt,yymmdd8.),substr(imst,1,2), substr(imst,3,2),0);
format date_time IS8601DT.;
run;
```

Now date_time is numeric and combines the date and the time in one variable. You can then select the min and max date using any method, I did it using proc sql, but you can probably think of other methods:

```
proc sql;
create table min_max_date as
select min(date_time) format = IS8601DT. as First_date
        ,max(date_time) format = IS8601DT. as Last_date
    from test;
quit;
```